# Golang GCP Storage Client Memory Leak

Tags: go, google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-storage

I've read the following issue on github https://github.com/googleapis/google-cloud-go/issues/1025 and found out there is a memory leak from the idle connections created so adding http client to the ClientOption does the trick. However i'd like to implement it with using 'WithCredentialsFile' option but turns out based on the documentation, 'WithHTTPClient' isn't compatible.

Below is my approach:

```
    client, err := storage.NewClient(ctx, option.WithCredentialsFile(cred), option.WithHTTPClient(httpClient))
    if err != nil {
        return err
    }
    defer client.Close()
```

And i always get the following error:

```
"googleapi: Error 401: Anonymous caller does not have storage.objects.create access to <filepath>, required"
```

Is there any workaround to this?

update:
i tried the following to get rid of withCred when calling newClient

```
    os.Setenv("GOOGLE_APPLICATION_CREDENTIALS", cre)

    client, err := storage.NewClient(ctx, option.WithHTTPClient(httpClient))
    if err != nil {
        return err
    }
    defer client.Close()
```

But it still resulted the above error. While if i try removing withHttp it results in memory leakage(atleast uploading works)

Comment: If I understand well, you want to use withCred and WithHttp into the same time but it doesn't work. Am I right? If so, where is running your code? On GCP environment?

Comment: @guillaumeblaquiere yes that is my approach. The WithHttp cancels out the withCred. Also, the service is indeed running on GCP environment.

Comment: Ok, if you run on GCP environment, the solution is easy: you don't need a credential file!! Use the default identity of your underlying service.

Comment: @guillaumeblaquiere could you perhaps provide a link or example for reference? i don't quite follow. thanks

Answer (score 1):

I don't know How you create your HttpClient. In any case, if you specify your HTTPClient, [it is used and this one by default not](https://github.com/googleapis/google-api-go-client/blob/214a0d2663ab0d218fc5fee8d44e96019beb1151/transport/http/dial.go#L44)

However, the used transport layer is this one of your HTTPClient. By default, it does not embed the security layer that the library create by default (and that use your credential). You have to reproduce this logic in your HTTPClient.

Thereby, when you call your endpoint, you call it without any security header and thus, your 401 error is normal.

Answer (score 0):

I believe this will allow you to use your own HTTP client.

```
    import {
       gcpTransport "google.golang.org/api/transport/http"
    }

    ...

    httpClient.Transport, err = gcpTransport.NewTransport(ctx, option.WithCredentialsFile(cred))
    if err != nil {
        return err
    }
    client, err := storage.NewClient(ctx, option.WithHTTPClient(httpClient))
    if err != nil {
        return err
    }
    defer client.Close()
```